# Is there a function where I can merge all columns of A to all columns of B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, textjoin

I have a situation in Excel where I want to combine all values of column A to to all values of column B (where I want to keep all values of B Absolute to All values of column A)

Example:
Column A - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
Column B -  A B C D E F G H

The result I want is 
1A
2A
3A
4A
5A
6A
7A
8A
1B
2B
3B
4B
5B so on till I reach 8H

I have tried simple concatenating but obviously it is taking too long

It would be appreciated if someone can look into this and provide me with a formula to help me fix this.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

After your post, I realized what you are really after.

In cell `C1` put:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($C$1)+1>COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),"",INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-ROW($C$1))/COUNTA(B:B)+1))&INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($C$1),COUNTA(B:B))+1))
```

And drag down

[image]

Comment: Hi Friend, thank you for your detailed explanation. I tried doing it but it isn't giving me desired results. Actually the values in Cell C is not something I am after. Sorry If my question was not clear. in column C1 I am looking for value 1A, in C2 2A, C3 3A and so on till I get results ending with 8G and 8H in column C. Sorry I dont know how to add screenshot here otherwise I would have done that. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've found this sollution, but in VBA. I hope it's okay for you. [That's how it look on my excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQWJc.png)

```
Sub Merge()

Dim NumberLeng As Range
Dim LetterLeng As Range
Dim LastLetter As Long
Dim LastNumber As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastMix As Long
Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastLetter = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'last letter
LastNumber = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last number

Set NumberRange = sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastNumber, 1)) ' range of numbers
Set LetterRange = sht.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(LastLetter, 2)) ' range of letters
X = 0
    For Each Letter In LetterRange

        For Each Number In NumberRange

        Number.Offset(X, 2) = Number & Letter 'Number+Letter

        Next Number

    LastMix = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'set new last
    X = LastMix

    Next Letter

End Sub
```

If there is any help needed go ahead and ask : )